# Database Structure and Querying

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, data-modeling

Trying to figure out how to change a structure from what I currently have which is this:

### tblHaulLogs

```
intLogID
intHaulType
intSerial
intOriginSource
intOrigin
intDestinationSource
intDestination
dtmHaulDate
ccyLogPay
intHauler
txtLogNotes
intInvoiceID
```

In this table, what I am doing is using the origin and destination source fields to determine which table the fk for the origin and destination comes from. This feels very wrong to me.

### tblHaulTypes

```
intHaulTypeID
chrHaulType
intOriginSourceType
intDestinationSourceType
```

### Data in the Haul Types Table:

```
LOT, 1, 1
DEL, 1, 2
RPO, 2, 1
```

Now let me explain:
The first type happens when an item goes from a sales lot to another sales lot. 
The second type happens when an item goes from a sales lot to a customer(sale gets delivered).
The third type happens when an item  returns from the customer back to the sales lot.

Then the Item can be resold/returned/resold/returned(rent-to-own system).
Now, here are the problems I have:

1. An Haul Log's origin will always be the destination of the last move. Therefore I thought that the origin field is redundant. However, it's the relation between the destination of the last move and the destination of the new move that defines what the shipper gets paid and what type of haul it is.

In other words, even though the first type and the third type technically have the same fields, the type of move is not the same because of the previous move type. What do I need to do here? Am I totally missing the boat on what the structure should be?

2. The questions I need to answer based on this data is:
   How many Items do I have on my sales lots that are new inventory(have never been sold).
   How many Items do I have that have been sold and returned(doesn't matter how many times).

Comment: I guess no one is answering your question because you are providing too many irrelevant details in your question. Also your table and attribute names are a bit strange and not self-explanatory. Is your question about the two different types of orders or the different types of item movements you have to deal with?

Comment: Revised question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: I guess this question deals with a similar but not quite the some issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838713/database-tables-more-the-better?rq=1
The real issue I am having is with question #1

Comment: When you say "An Haul Log's origin will always be the destination of the last move", you probably mean "The origin of an item's haul is the destination of its last move", do you? Why is there no reference to the hauled item in the log table?

Comment: The intSerial field is the serial # of the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing at the relationship between the various fields and tables.

Your **tblHaulTypes** table looks fine.

```
intHaulTypeID
chrHaulType
intOriginSourceType
intDestinationSourceType
```

You're missing a haul type that accounts for deliveries from suppliers to your lots.

There has to be some table that lists your lots.  I'd call it **tblHaulLot**.

```
intLotNumber
txtLotName
...
```

I'd make a **tblHaulTransaction** table that looks like this.

```
intTransactionID
intHaulTypeID
intHauler
intOriginOrganizationID
intDestinationOrganizationID
intOriginLot      (null if origin is supplier)
intDestinationLot (null if destination is customer)
dtmHaulDate
txtLogNotes
```

Now, we need an **tblOrganization**.

```
intOrganizationID
txtOrganizationName
txtOrganizationAddress
...
```

The organization at ID 0 is your organization.  Suppliers and customers would fill the rest of the table.

I'd make a **tblHaulInvoice** table that looks like this.

```
intInvoiceID
intTransactionID
ccyTransactionPay
dtmDateInvoiced
AmountInvoiced
```

The amount invoiced (and amount paid) have to be accounted for in some table.  I don't know what ccy stands for, and I don't know your 3 letter code for a decimal (money) field.

> How many Items do I have on my sales lots that are new inventory(have never been sold). How many Items do I have that have been sold and returned(doesn't matter how many times).

Nowhere in your data model is there any kind of inventory table.  I'd need to know a lot more about your business to create one or more inventory tables.

Comment: What is the origin is a customer?(repo)

Comment: I meant what if the origin of a haul transaction is a customer.

Comment: @Freeman Helmuth:  Ok, the origin is null if the origin is a supplier or the customer.

Comment: So how do I know who the customer or supplier was? Since an item can be resold multiple times I need to know which sale the log transaction was for

Comment: Btw, ccy is currency. intSerial is the item

Comment: @Freeman Helmuth: I added an organization table to the answer.

Comment: So you are saying if the destination is a Sales Lot, I would fill in the Destination Lot Field, if it's a customer, I would fill in the Destination Organization field?

Comment: Although I didn't end up using this exact method, this helped me find the problem in the structure and answered my question. Thanks!